# JAVA | Saving file path

Tags: java, path

So I wanted to save files needed for the program, but the user has to decide where to save files... But because I dont want the user to select the path everytime he starts the program, the program should save the path where to go to find the files, how to?

I made the user select the file with a JFileChooser.

```
    JButton jButton = new JButton();
    JFileChooser jFileChooser = new JFileChooser();
    jFileChooser.setCurrentDirectory(new File(System.getProperty("user.home")));
    jFileChooser.setDialogTitle("Choose your Path!");
    jFileChooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
    if(jFileChooser.showOpenDialog(jButton) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){

    }
    path = jFileChooser.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath();
    pathBind = jFileChooser.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath() + "/binds.jar";

    bindFile = new File(pathBind);
```

If any further information is needed, I'll give it... Sorry if I forgot something^^.

Comment: You can save the directory in another file. Save that file in the user's directory. Use `System.getProperty("user.home")` to select the user's home directory.

Comment: I thought so, but the program cant remember the path of that file either, or am I wrong? //EDIT: Nevermind, I'll try doing that. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 1):

That kind of information probably belongs in user preferences, which you access using the [Preferences](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/prefs/Preferences.html) class:

```
private static final String LAST_SAVE_DIR_PREFS_KEY = "last-save-dir";

private static final Preferences PREFERENCES =
    Preferences.userNodeForPackage(MyUserInterface.class);

// ...

    String saveDir = PREFERENCES.get(LAST_SAVE_DIR_PREFS_KEY,
        System.getProperty("user.home"));
    jFileChooser.setSelectedFile(new File(saveDir));

    jFileChooser.setDialogTitle("Choose your Path!");
    jFileChooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
    if (jFileChooser.showOpenDialog(jButton) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {

        PREFERENCES.put(LAST_SAVE_DIR_PREFS_KEY,
            jFileChooser.getSelectedFile().toString());

        // ...
    }
```